# Visual Studio: How to add linked item between folders within the same project?

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to share a common .targets file between different folders within the same project (using Visual Studio 2015):

- MyProject

  - MyNupkgContent1

    - build

      - MyNupkgContent1.props
      - Common.targets
  - MyNupkgContent2

    - build

      - MyNupkgContent2.props
      - Common.targets <-- should be added as link

When I try to "add as linked" Common.targets to MyNupkgContent2/build, the dialog closes but does not actually add the link.  Adding files as links from a different project works fine.  Is it possible to link files between folders in the same project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 - How to add a file link to a file in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289743/visual-studio-2012-how-to-add-a-file-link-to-a-file-in-the-same-project)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain as to how you should go about linking it but depending on contents and size of application, your best bet may be simply going into your packages and manually copying + pasting them into MyNupkgContent2

Comment: Yes, I'm already taking the copy-paste approach.  Looking for a solution that's a little more sustainable.

Comment: Hmm... have you tried a separate folder/package for the shared file(s)? I know you want the packages to share the targets but this would be my next idea.

Comment: I did try putting the target into a separate project, but it looks like VS linking may not be the way to go - the link is managed internally to VS, but packaging happens from the command line, so the file doesn't actually exist in the target location at the time of packaging.  I tried to use a Windows shortcut with a relative path as well, but Nuget simply packages the shortcut instead of the file it points to.  I find it surprisingly difficult to reuse common build content across different nuget packages.